# An output problem while converting from decimal to binary in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, binary, type-conversion, decimal, x86-16

I was writing a code in assembly 8086 were you have to input a decimal number and it converts it to a binary one, but I face a problem with the output. The output is fine from numbers 1 to 2559, but when I input 2560 it outputs 0 (actually it prints empty line, but the value is 0).
It prints like this:

dec: 2558 - binary: 1001 1111 1110
dec: 2559 - binary: 1001 1111 1111
dec: 2560 - binary: nothing (but the value is 0)
dec: 2561 - binary: 1
dec: 2562 - binary: 10
dec: 2563 - binary: 11

Here is the code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    message1 db "Enter a decimal number: $"
    message2 db "Binary number: $"
    message3 db "Success!", 10, 13,'$'
    new_line db 10,13,'$'
    number dw 0
.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, message1
    int 21h
    
    mov bl, 10
    
    input:
        mov dx, 0
        mov ah, 1
        int 21h
        
        cmp al, 13
        je next
        
        sub al, 48
        mov ah, 0
        
        mov dx, ax
        mov ax, number
        mul bl
        
        add ax, dx
        
        mov number, ax
        
        jmp input
    next:
        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, new_line
        int 21h
    
        mov ax, number
        mov cx, 0
        mov dx, 0
    converting:
        cmp ax, 0
        je msg
        
        mov bx, 2
        div bx
        push dx
        inc cx
        mov dx, 0
        jmp converting
    msg:
        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, message2
        int 21h
    printing:
        cmp cx, 0
        je the_end
        
        pop dx
        add dx, 48
        
        mov ah, 2
        int 21h
        dec cx
        jmp printing
        
    the_end:
        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, new_line
        int 21h

        mov ah, 9
        lea dx, message3
        int 21h
    
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
end
```

I don't know where the problem can be. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: One bug is that `mul bl` only does `AX = AL * BL`, so it truncates your total to 8-bit every step.  Numbers larger than 2560 will be wrong.  (And `2560` itself will come out zero when you  multiply the low half of `0x0100` byte 0xa and then add `'0'`).  Use `mov bx, 10` / `mul bx`.  (But beware that overwrites DX.  Use `imul ax, ax, 10` if you can use 186 new instructions.  Or just pick a different scratch reg like CX in that loop.)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> mul bl
> ```

You're using the **byte-sized** multiplication that calculates AL times BL. Since you seem to expect to be able to work with numbers that no longer fit in a byte, so GT 255, you would better use the **word-sized** multiplication.
Knowing that the word-sized multiplication uses DX:AX as its destination, some re-organizing of the code is needed:

```
input:
    mov  ah, 01h   ; DOS.GetCharacter
    int  21h       ; -> AL
    cmp  al, 13
    je   next
    sub  al, 48    ; Convert from ["0","9"] to [0,9]
    cbw            ; -> AX holds the new digit
    mov  bx, 10
    xchg bx, ax    ; -> AX is 10, BX holds the new digit
    mul  number    ; Your assembler knows this is a word-sized multiplication
    add  ax, bx    ; Number * 10 + NewDigit
    mov  number, ax
    jmp  input
next:
```

---

> ```
> mov bx, 2
> div bx
> ```

*A conversion into binary should never be using an actual division by 2*. Just shift the number to the right, then add the carry from that SHR to the character '0'. If the CF=0 the character will remain '0', and if the CF=1 the character will become '1'.
If the number is zero, you would still want to display a single '0' digit, instead of leaving an empty line which I believe is more confusing.

```
    mov  ax, number
    xor  cx, cx    ; Number of binary digits [1,16]
converting:
    inc  cx
    mov  dx, '0'
    shr  ax, 1     ; -> CF
    adc  dx, 0
    push dx        ; (*)
    test ax, ax
    jnz  converting
```

Printing then transforms into next simpler code:

```
printing:
    pop  dx        ; (*)
    mov  ah, 02h   ; DOS.PrintCharacter
    int  21h
    loop printing
```

Comment: You don't need to store/reload to `number` inside the multiply loop; that's horrible.   CX is unused in that loop.  If you can't use `imul cx, 10` / `add cx, ax` to also avoid clobbering DX, then there's a lot you could do, although some of it might be less readable or intuitive.  e.g. maybe have CX zeroed so `mov cl, al` zero-extends, and `mov ax, bx` (total) ; `mul si` (10) ; `mov bx, cx` ; `add bx, ax`.  Hmm, that's 3 mov instructions, but I'm replacing xchg+mov+cbw, not just 1 xchg, while needing some setup outside the loop.  (Without hoisting the `10`, `mov dx, 10` / `mul dx` is good.)

Comment: Your code looks good if optimizing for code size, though, except the store/reload of `number`.  Since performance probably doesn't matter for an interactive input loop, it's probably ok to use `mul` instead of shift/add, even though `mul` is very slow on 8086.  And this is not too different from the OP's code so maybe easier for them to understand.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was tempted to not use the `memory` variable within that loop, but the reason I did that store/reload to `number` inside the multiply loop is that I expressly wanted to demonstrate that the `mul` instruction *can* work with a memory-based operand. All too often I see people doing all kinds of register acrobatics so they can do `mul <reg>` (probably thinking that it's the only syntax allowed).

Comment: Oh, yeah that is weird in the code in the question.  I wonder if they had tried `mov al, 10` / `mul number` and gotten high garbage (due to non-zero AH).  Probably not.